# How to iterate trough row and then trough column in a 2D array?

Tags: java, for-loop, matrix

I have a 2D array and i want to find the minimum value of each row and column. But, for example: lets say i have a 5x5 symmetric matrix like

```
int matrix [ ][ ] = 
{ { 0, 8, 3, 7, 10 },
{ 8, 0, 5, 9, 4 },
{ 3, 5, 0, 6, 7 },
{ 7, 9, 6, 0, 9 },
{ 10, 4, 7, 9, 0 } }
```

If i start from row 2 i should iterate through 8,0,5,9,4 and i should print number 4 because its the min value (im not considering 0) then i should start to iterate through the column exactly where i left or ended. So i should start iterating again but starting from index[4] and the col would be 10, 4, 7, 9, 0 and the min col value is going to be 7 (without considering the previous min value which was 4 and 0) and so on...

I thought i could use another nested for that considered the new index as the starting point for the loop but then im not sure how to go back to iterating through the rows

```
int menor = matriz[1][0];
int i, j, indice = 0;

for (i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {

    if (menor > matriz[1][i] && matriz[1][i] != 0 || menor == 0) {
        menor = matriz[1][i];
        indice = i;
    }
    System.out.print("Elemento ubicado en " + i + " : ");
    System.out.println(matriz[1][i] + " ");

}
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Elemento menor es " + menor + " el cual esta ubicado: " + indice);
```

My final output should be something like 4, 7, 3, 7, 9

Comment: the processing you describe is unclear. why do you start at row 2 and why then go to column 4? why not iterate on all rows and then on all columns?

Comment: This is just a specific case. I just wanted to know if is possible to do that. The thing i want to do is go row->column->row and so on until there is no more to iterate. Is there a different way to do the comparison?

Comment: yes, the most obvious way - iterate on all rows and then iterate on all columns